# If $A \subseteq B$, then $A\Delta B=B\backslash A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So I'm working on my discrete math homework, and I came to this one:
If $A \subseteq B$, then $A\Delta B=B\backslash A$
I was getting it split up into cases to prove it, then I noticed that it was $B\backslash A$, and that didn't make sense to me. If it was $A\backslash A$ that would make sense to me because then both $A\Delta B$ and $A\backslash A$ would equal $\emptyset$, but I don't see any way that $B\backslash A$ could equal $A\Delta B$.

Comment: Write down the definition of $A\Delta B$, and you will see what it is equal to.

Comment: If you’re confused about this, you might want to use some specific examples. Say, $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and calculate $A \Delta B$ and $B \setminus A$.

Comment: I think you are confusing $M\Delta N$ with $M \setminus N$.   $M\Delta N$ is "all the things that are in one or another of $M$ or $N$ but not in both".  Or formally either 1)  $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$ or 2) $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$.  If you understand the actual meaning of $A \Delta B$ then this should be utterly intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \subset B$, then $A-B= \phi$, thus,

$A \triangle B = (A- B) \cup B-A=\phi \cup (B-A)=B-A$

Comment: But doesn't $A\Delta B = A \backslash B \bigcup B \backslash A$?

Comment: I SEE!!! Since $A\backslash B = \emptyset $, then $A\Delta B = B\backslash A$!!!

Comment: Hello, you can use \emptyset for the empty set $\emptyset$.

Comment: @Hayden: better to use parentheses A\Delta B = $(A \setminus B) \bigcup (B \setminus A)$ since you would obtain different results by doing computations in various orders: for example, $(A \setminus B) \bigcup (B \setminus A)
 \neq ((A \setminus B) \bigcup B) \setminus A)$ in general

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out! Would have been bad if I messed something up for that simple mistake. Thanks for all of the help guys!!

Comment: I think you have a typo in that $A\Delta B = (A-B)\color{red}\cup \color{green}(B-A\color{green})$ (and also  $\emptyset \color{red}\cap ANYTHING = \emptyset$ and not $B-A$.)

Comment: Just a tiny nit-pick: The standard symbol for the empty set is not a stylized Greek ϕ, it is a stylized Norwegian ø. There are two common commands for it, `\emptyset` $\emptyset$ or my personal preference: `\varnothing` $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Hayden sorry, it was a latex typo

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $A\Delta B$ are the elements that are in $A$ or $B$ but not in both. If $A\subseteq B$ then the elements that are in $A$ are automatically in $B$ but the elements in $B\setminus A$ are not in $A$. Therefore $A\Delta B=B\setminus A$.